# Break down multidimensional array and loop into wpdb update

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [72] => Array
      (
        [description] => data
        [tags] => data1
        [extra] => data1
        [extra2] => data3
      )
    [71] => Array
      (
        [extra] => data4
        [extra2] => data5
      )
    [73] => Array
      (
        [description] => data7
        [tags] => data6
      )
)
```

Which I want to put this into a sql update statement. The first level of the array is the unique key which I need to set to the WHERE clause, and the rest of the data is the column names with its respective value.  This data varies based on what the user sets.

EDIT:  this was incredibly easy.

```
foreach($save as $id => $arr) {
    $wpdb->update( $table_name, $arr, array('id' => $id));
}
```

This however, doesn't use `wpdb prepare`, which seems necessary.  How can I manipulate this code to allow for `wpdb-prepare`?

The only code I found on wpdb prepare and update looks like this:

```
$rows_affected = $wpdb->query(
            $wpdb->prepare("
               UPDATE $table
               SET ( removed, post_id, user_id, status )
               VALUES ( %s, %d, %d, %d )
               ",
               array(
                $cur_date,
                $postid,
                $userid,
                0
            )
        )
    );
```

Comment: What is the question? What is the problem? What fails?

Comment: Why cant you just loop through the first level of array and create your update statement from an inner loop with key value pair. Try it and come back with any issues

Comment: I guess I'm missing the question, which is, how do I do this? @Farrukh I'm horrible with arrays.  I know I need to use a `foreach($array as $arr)` but I don't know how I reference the second level of the array.  Just `$arr[0]`?

Comment: when you get the first level you know that second level is an array so just get its count and iterate as a loop similar to first level.

Comment: @FarrukhSubhani Well, the first part was easy peasy.  Mayhaps you can help on the question I edited in above?

Comment: Do you know about key($arr) which gives the name of the key so wpdb->prepare requires a new array but the first argument is a string you can build this string up and its corresponding array using all of the above code and key($arr). Loop through keys and create update statement with %s or %d conditions and pass both array and sring to prepare. It will make sure nothing illegal goes forward.

Comment: @FarrukhSubhani turns out you can't use key($arr) inside a foreach, which took me forever to figure out.  Even more importantly, however, it turns out that wpdb->update already prepares and sanitizes for me!  so Im all set.  i did find out that I could just throw a foreach in a foreach to get each secondary key!

Answer (score 0):

So just to answer this,
You have figured out that

1. You can use foreach in another foreach and it would iterate through items.
2. update function already prepares and sanitize for you so no need to call wp prepare function.

Happy days.